# Accessing properties of a tableview in other functions

Tags: ios, swift

How can I access the `indexPath` value/parameter of the table view functions in another function of the class? For example: if I have the following code below how can I pass the value of `indexPath` to the `IBAction` below?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var index = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    // HOW CAN I ACCESS THE VAR INDEX IN THE IBACTION BELOW
}

@IBAction func nextDay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    cday -= 1
    Main(currentDay: cday, compDay: comparingDay, cIndex: index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `index` variable outside the function scope:

```
var index: Any?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = dataSource[indexPath.row]
}

@IBAction func nextDay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    cday -= 1
    Main(currentDay: cday, compDay: comparingDay, cIndex: index)

}
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem with this is that index only gets updated if I change or touch the table view

Comment: Definitely. The method is `didSelectRow`. It's meant to be called only if you select that row and only then the `index` is updated.